# creating wordpress theme using bootstrap and having issues with registering menu area

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a WordPress theme from scratch using bootstrap
I am using a file I got from GitHub and have implemented a lot of things from it. You can find it in Github . The name is : 
twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

now I am creating menus / registering menu area and have used the following code :

```
<?php 
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

//theme support
function theme_setup(){
//nav menu
    register_nav_menus(array(
      'primary' => __('Primary Menu')
    ));
}
//for the above function to work we need tocreate an addaction function, which lets us choose a hook to run it
//the one we want is aftr set up theme

  add_action('after_setup_theme','wpb_theme_setup');
```

After doing this the menu shows up but there is an error above it which is :

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpb_theme_setup' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-includes\plugin.php on line525
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  241464  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0007  244632  require( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-blog-header.php' )   ..\index.php:17
3   0.0011  264688  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-load.php' ) ..\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0016  275768  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-config.php' )   ..\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0027  402232  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-settings.php' ) ..\wp-config.php:89
6   0.3356  21979856    do_action( )    ..\wp-settings.php:377
7   0.3357  21981408    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\wordpress-bootstrap\bootstrap\wp-includes\plugin.php:525} ( )
```

I dont know how to solve this error or what to do about it. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Change `function theme_setup(){` to `function wpb_theme_setup(){`

The hook `add_action('after_setup_theme','theme_setup');` is trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: You're welcome. You might click the "accept answer" box so others will know the question has been answered.